# How to print Google Maps with cluster (clusterer) icons?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, printing, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have to print some Google Maps displayed within PHP application.

Basically, I can print it, and what is important markers are printed correctly. But problem occurs if I need to print cluster. Instead of cluster icon, only a white box is printed (in fact that part of the map is not printed at all), and only number of markers that that cluster contain is printed in that box.

I tried with custom icon, and result is the same.

Is it **possible to print anything anyhow as a clusterer (icon)**, with number of grouped markers inside? At least to put some color in the box? It does not have to be icon, is it possible to set color of that empty box with styles?

Tnx in advance!

Comment: I'm getting the same result in FF8 - have you tried other browsers? This is clearly a bug! I think it shall be reported to either Firefox or markerclusterer developers (depends on how other browsers handle it).

Answer (score 4):

Printing is not available with MarkerClusterer, but it is an option if you use an enhancement named: [MarkerClustererPlus](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerClustererPlus). It is essentially a Google Maps v3 upgrade of the original v2 MarkerClusterer, which was then further enhanced and extended by Gary Little. It functions pretty much the same as the v3 MarkerClusterer, but offers more options[<sup>doc</sup>](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/docs/reference.html).

Specific to your question, you may pass a set of options to the `MarkerClusterer` constructor function (when using **MarkerClustererPlus**) and include an option: `printable`. If set to `true`, it will give you what you want. I have noticed that setting `printable` to `true` may cause you to adjust the placement of the cluster count label within the cluster marker icon, but it usually just takes some tweaking. Most importantly, the cluster icon and the count label will appear in map prints.

Comment: Hi, since Google removed the code from Google Code i've looked for this MarkerClusterPlus but everywhere i looked (github and the like) i cant seem to find any version that receives a printable option. Any thoughts where i could find it?

Comment: I was having the same issue, and found MarkerClustererPlus [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js) on GoogleMaps' GitHub. I was very lucky in that all I did was download the .js file, and pull in this new `markerclustererplus.js` file instead of `markerclusterer.js` in my `<script>` tags, so at least for me it was completely backwards compatible with the original library! **Note that I did NOT have to include the `printable` option, it just worked right out of the gate** simply by using the plus library instead.